# Manhwa or manga in which the main character is weak and constantly compared to his father. He uses a forbidden spell to gain recognition

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

The main character is the son of a legendary hero/adventurer.

I believe he starts out weak, I can not remember, but keeps getting compared to his dad or by his dad's name and it makes him mad. The last thing I remember is a scene where he is in an arena fight and uses a forbidden spell or demon magic, I believe, to try to get recognition for his own strength.

His dad, I believe, has long white or blond hair and glasses.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the main character?

Comment: This question is quite terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774). For example, what was the main character's name? Was this aimed at grown-up (with sex and gore) or younger audiences? Was it a strip or a panelled manga? What did the forbidden spell do? Why was it forbidden? Who forbade it? Were there non-forbidden spells as well? How should he have fought, if not with magic? Was there a love interest? Who was doing the comparing to his father? What was the setting (medieval, fantasy, etc)?

Comment: Mostly black and white with like the occasional color image and the MC was black hair i believe

Comment: Does the MC use any physical weapons or items in battle, such as a sword or staff? If so, what?

Comment: A sword I think sorry I don't have more info.

Comment: Any idea where in the story the arena fight with the forbidden spell takes place? Chapter 1? 5? 40?

Comment: I think maybe within the first 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foud it
Kindan Shitei de Breakthrough or A Breakthrough brought by forbidden master and disciple.

I want to thank everyone for there replies and trying to help find or look for it. I know it wasn't much to go on and it was my first time using the site I appreciate it!

Comment: You will be able to accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark in about a day. We'd be much obliged if you did so.